# Complex integral $z^2 \sin(\bar z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration

I want to evaluate
$$
\int_{\partial B_1(0)} z^2\sin(\bar z)~\mathrm{d}z.
$$
We know that the integrand is not holomorphic. We can write
$$
\int_{\partial B_1(0)} z^2\sin(\bar z)~\mathrm{d}z = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\bar z^{2k+1}z^2(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} ~\mathrm{d}z.
$$
Can I now interchange sum and integral? Is it then true, that all integrals execept for the case $k=1$ vanish, such that
$$
\int_{\partial B_1(0)} z^2\sin(\bar z)~\mathrm{d}z = -\frac{2 \pi i}{6}?
$$

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, on the unit disc, $\overline{z}=\frac{1}{z}$, so the integral in question is the same as $\int_{|z|=1}z^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\,dz$, which one can evaluate using residues to also get $2\pi i \cdot \left(\frac{-1}{3!}\right)$ (ok in all honesty, it's pretty much the same computation as what you have done, just presented slightly differently).

Comment: This is more elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series for $\sin z$ conveges uniformly on compact sets and this implies that the series for $z^{2}\sin (\overline z)$ does the same. So you are justified in interchanging the sum and the integral. Your computation is correct and you have got the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. Are my further proceedings correct?

Comment: @Meowdog I have edited.

Comment: Thank you very much!